# Missing methods in Apify.utils.puppeteer Object

Tags: apify

if I 'require' Apify and check Apify.utils.puppeteer for it's methods with the Chrome debugger, there are missing some methods which are documented. Please compare with [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dw73.png):

`gotoExtended()`
`addInterceptRequestHandler()`
`removeInterceptRequestHandler()`
`infiniteScroll()`

Where are these methods gone?`

Cheers Wolfgang

Comment: I just tested it and all the functions are there. Which version of `apify` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are using an old version of Apify SDK. Can you check if you are using the version at least version 0.14.*? We added these function it [this version](https://github.com/apifytech/apify-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0140--2019-04-15).